# Why is my KeyListener not getting called?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, event-listener

I'm working on a school project that has two images...a good guy and a bad guy. I'm using a timer to send the bad guy towards the good guy and that is working find, but I'm supposed to use a KeyListener to move the good guy towards or away from the bad guy....and then eventually attack but that is for later.

I'm just trying to get my "good guy" to move on KeyListener and its not getting called. I have no idea why.

Here is my constructor which calls my EventLIstener in my main panel:

```
//monster 1 coordinates
int mon1x = 0;
int mon1y = 300;

KeyListenerAction myKeyActionListener = new KeyListenerAction();

public BlobFighterPanel()
{
    addKeyListener(myKeyActionListener);

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300,600)); //set size of main panel

    //add button
    startButton.addActionListener(startListener);
    add(startButton);
}
```

Then below I have my KeyListener, but its not getting called:

```
public class KeyListenerAction implements KeyListener  {

    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch(event.getKeyCode())
        {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            goodx -= 10;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            System.out.println("Right");
            goodx += 10;
            break;
        }

        repaint();
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event){}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event){}

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is my KeyListener not being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KeyListener` is fickle mistress.  It what's all the attention all the time or it isn't going to talk to you.  What does this mean?  In order for a `KeyListener` to raise events, the component is registered to must HAVE focus AND be focusable...

This means that the moment that another component becomes focused (like a button), the `KeyListener` will no longer respond.

Instead, you should use the key binding API, which was designed to overcome this issue.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: I think this is exactly what I needed. When I added the code setFocusable(true); I was then able to move my "monster", but after I click my start button the focus goes to the button. Can I set the focus on button click to a different panel?